# Double dispatch and template class

Tags: c++, templates, double-dispatch

I have a C++ code where I compare different class deriving from a common mother class, `Foo`. If the two class have not the same type, the comparison is always `false`. Otherwise, it compares some internal data specific to the class.

My code looks like this:

```
class Bar;
class Baz;

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual bool isSame( Foo* ) = 0;
    virtual bool isSameSpecific( Bar* ){ return false; }
    virtual bool isSameSpecific( Baz* ){ return false; }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    bool isSame( Foo* foo){ return foo->isSameSpecific(this); }
    bool isSameSpecific( Bar* bar){ return bar->identifier == identifier; }

    int identifier;
};

// and the same for Baz...
```

This works great (I think that's a double dispatch), I can compare `Bar` and `Baz` with only pointers to `Foo`.

But now comes the problem. I have to add a template class:

```
template< typename T>
class Qux : public Foo
{
//...
};
```

The problem is that in `Foo`, I cannot declare the method `isSameSpecific` for `Qux*`, because it would be virtual and template.

**Question**: is there any neat way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Only make `Foo` class template also, or write different overloads of `isSameSpecific` for all needed `Qux<T>`.

Comment: @ForEveR Thank you for your comment! The template argument does not make sense on Foo and futur classes might have other template arguments, so I don't want to end up with all the possible template arguments on Foo. For the different overloads, this could be an acceptable solution, but there can be many possibilites for T, so many overloads to write (not very neat).

Comment: Have a look at Andrei Alexandrescu's [Loki Library](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/), in particular the [Visitor](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Pattern.Visitor) pattern.

Comment: @PeterWood Interesting, I'll have a look at it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really a solution for this problem: you need
a `isSameSpecific` function for each instantiation of the
template you use.  (In other words, in `Foo`:

```
template <typename T>
virtual bool isSameSpecific( Qux<T>* );
```

is illegal, but:

```
virtual bool isSameSpecific( Qux<int>* );
virtual bool isSameSpecific( Qux<double>* );
//  etc.
```

isn't.)

You might be able to get away with creating an abstract 
`QuxBase`, and having `Qux<T>` derive from it.  Most likely,
that will just move the problem to `QuxBase`, but if
`isSameSpecific` doesn't depend on the type of `T`, for example
because you can define some canonical encompassing type, it may
be doable.  Without knowing more about `Qux` and
`isSameSpecific`, it's difficult to say.  (If
`Qux<T>::isSameSpecific` should always return `false` if the
instantiation types are different, for example, you could type
check in `QuxBase::isSameSpecific`, and forward to another
virtual function if the types are identical.)

Note that similar issues affect all of the alternative ways of
implementing multiple dispatch as well.  In the end, you're
asking for dispatch over an open set of types, which means
a potentially infinit number of different functions.

### EDIT:

Just to be clear: I am assuming that your `isSame` is simply an
example, and that the actual operations may be more complex.
The actual code you show clearly falls into what I suggest in
the second paragraph; in fact, it can be implemented even
without multiple dispatch.  Just define a canonical "identifier"
type, define a virtual `getCanonicalIdentifier` function, and
use that in `isSame`:

```
bool Foo::isSame( Foo const* other ) const
{
    return getCanonicalIdentifier() 
        == other->getCanonicalIdentifier(); 
}
```

For that matter, if different types implies that `isSame`
returns false (often the case, if `isSame` means what it looks
like), all you don't need double dispatch either:

```
bool Foo::isSame( Foo const* other ) const
{
    return typeid( *this ) == typeid( *other )
        && isSameSpecific( other );
}
```

The derived `isSameSpecific` will have to convert the type of
the pointer, but since they are guaranteed that it is the same
as the type of `this`, that's a simple and safe operation.

Finally: if the classes don't have value semantics (and the
almost certainly shouldn't if polymorphism is involved),
something as simple as:

```
bool Foo::isSame( Foo const* other ) const
{
    return this == other;
}
```

may suffice.

All of this applies *only* to something like `isSame`, however.
If you have other functions as which are affected, you're back
to what I initially said.

Comment: Thanks for the very interesting answer! You're right when you say that the implementation is quite more complex, but that's the heart of my problem. I think actually that your idea with the QuxBase solves my problem! Actually, the type T is usually a class (on which I have full control) with data in it. So, I can make all the potential T derive from one class and have a method (double dispatch again) to compare them. Then, in QuxBase, I can compare both the data specific from Qux and compare the type T throught the comparison method.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler must know the (finite) set of `isSameSpecific` virtuals at the time it parses the `class Foo` definition.  The virtuals all have reserved entries in the vtable.  The template `Qux` could be overridden an unlimited number of times, requiring an unlimited number of virtuals in `Foo`.  Clearly that can't work, even without trying to describe a method of defining them all.

You can probably use typeinfo to do what you want, but it would not be with type polymorphism.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's what I thought and that's the problem with every "template virtual" method. Typeinfo is my default solution but it do not consider it as *neat*. So, maybe the solution is indeed to change my definition of *neat*.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that this is double-dispatch, and you are right that unfortunately a method cannot be both `virtual` and `template` (the latter being an implementation issue).

I am afraid that there is no possibility to do so with a *pure* design; however you can cheat in `Qux`.

```
template <typename T>
class Qux: public Foo {
    virtual bool isSame( Foo* foo ) {
        if (Qux* q = dynamic_cast<Qux*>(foo)) {
            return *this == *q;
        }
        return false;
    }
}; // class Qux
```

Of course, `dynamic_cast` is cheating a bit (as are all casts toward children), but hey *it works*!

Nota Bene: the `isSame` methods should be probably be `const` and take `const` arguments, aka `virtual bool isSame(Foo const* foo) const;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your solution is probably the one I'll implement (actually, I'll probably do that in all the isSame method and get rid of the isSameSpecific), unless some comes with a better idea. And yes, the cast is not in my *neat* defintition :-). For your NB: in my implementation, it's actually const, since it was not essential for the understanding of the problem, I got rid of it. Thank for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: Not cheating one little bit. The cast here is not essential to the design, it is just to overcome a language limitation.

Comment: If this is a sufficient solution, you can do the type check in the base class, and only forward to `isSameSpecific` if the two types are identical.  And if `isSame` should always return `false` if they aren't, then doing the check in the base class is probably a better solution (even if it involves RTTI), since you enforce the post-condition in the base class.

Comment: @JamesKanze: it would be slightly different though, as it is the solution I presented allows comparing `Qux<int>` against `class K: public Qux<int> {};` (for better or worse). What would be the signature of `isSameSpecific` though in your case ? `Foo*` too ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. The signature would have to be with `Foo*`, since for overriding to work, the signatures all have to be the same.  So each derived class would have to convert the argument to its type.  Because this is a precondition of the function, however, it could use `static_cast`.  (And of course, the virtual function should be private, to ensure that it is never called except from `isSame` in the base class.)

Answer (score 1):

How about using RTTI:

```
#include <typeinfo>

struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo() { }
    virtual bool compare_with_same(Foo const & rhs) = 0;
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
    int thing;

    virtual bool compare_with_same(Foo const & rhs)
    {
        assert(dynamic_cast<Bar const *>(&rhs) != nullptr);

        return static_cast<Bar const &>(rhs).thing == thing;
    }
}

bool operator==(Foo const & lhs Foo const & rhs)
{
    return typeid(lhs) == typeid(rhs) && lhs.compare_with_same(rhs);
}
```

Alternatively you can put the `typeid` code into each `compare_with_same` override. That might be a bit safer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! RTTI does not meet my definition of *neat*, but I think that I'll have no choice... It's maybe more my definition of *neat* that is wrong :-)

Comment: @Dr_Sam It may be your definition of _neat_.  If there is a post-condition `typeid(lhs) != typeid(rhs)` implies `false`, then this should be enforced in the base class; the proposed solution here, with `typeid` is actually cleaner than depending on every derived class doing this correctly (i.e. only overriding the `isSameSpecific` for its own class).

Comment: @Dr_Sam Note too that if you have an invariant that all instances have different identifiers, then `bool Foo::isSame( Foo const* other ) const { return this == other; }` is by far the simplest solution.

Comment: @JamesKanze  There's not identifier, unfortunately. For the comparison in the mother class, you're right!